# Violation of primary key after switch partition (stage>dbo)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

Would someone help, please, to get rid of the error:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_stmp_tst1'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.stmp_tst'. The duplicate key value is (1).

which occurs after switch partition of the table.

Full SQL Script below:

I. Create 2 equal tables in different schemas:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.stmp_tst(
    [inn] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_stmp_tst] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
go


CREATE TABLE stage.stmp_tst(
    [inn] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_stmp_tst] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

II. Insert data into stage table.

```
insert into stage.stmp_tst (inn)
select '1111'
```

III. Switch-partition stage to dbo.

```
alter table stage.stmp_tst switch partition 1 to dbo.stmp_tst partition 1;
```

IV. Add data to dbo table.

```
insert into dbo.stmp_tst (inn)
select '1111'
```

V. We have the error:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_stmp_tst1'. Cannot insert
> duplicate key in object 'dbo.stmp_tst'. The duplicate key value is
> (1).

IV. Drop temporary tables:

```
drop table dbo.stmp_tst
drop table stage.stmp_tst
```

It can be solved by the query:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('dbo.stmp_tst', RESEED);
```

but reseeding takes time.
Is it possible to do a switch-partition correctly without reseed?
Thank you.

Comment: First of all, the oldest SQL Server version is mainstream support is SQL Server **2019**. 2008 is way, way too old. Second, the problem is caused by storing a bunch of IDENTITY values into one table then moving them to another empty table, that knew nothing about the modified seed. You *must* tell the table to change its starting seed to avoid conflicts, with `DBCC CHECKIDENT ('dbo.stmp_tst', RESEED, some_new_value);`. Even `RESEED` alone shouldn't take long if the `ID` field is indexed. It only needs to find the `MAX(ID)`. If that's slow, you have other problems too.

Comment: Since 2014 you can use [SEQUENCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) instead of IDENTITY to generate key values for multiple tables. That alone eliminates conflicts and the need to reseed. If the ID field isn't indexed (why?) you can specify the new seed explicitly with `,RESEED, 1234567..)` based on what was inserted into the partition

Comment: Panagiotis Kanavos, thank you. I have 2017 MSSQL version. Can I assign primary key to SEQUENCE?

Comment: @AlexIvanov, you can create a PK on the bigint column regardless of whether the value is assigned by IDENTITY, SEQUENCE,, or other means.